# Historical data of Kraken (bid-ask)

Tags: historical-trade-data

How can I buy or download the data of Kraken bitcoin trades 2015-2016 in cvs format. I need it for my trading strategy (time stamp, volumes, bid, ask)
can someone help me or make for me?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best option for you would be to write a script which grabs the data from Kraken's API, and parses that into a CSV output that you want.

Using the API to download trade history is explained here:
https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/218198197-How-to-pull-all-trade-data-using-the-Kraken-REST-API?mobile_site=true

Answer (score 0):

they do have downloadable data here,
https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047543791-Downloadable-historical-market-data-time-and-sales-

but these are all only trades.
the Spread is missing.

as far as i figured all possibilities out... their api seems to let you see only ~2 minutes into the past regarding the spread between bid+ask.